# Resample from data keeping factor distribution of specific variables

Tags: r, sample

I would like to resample my data with replacement while also keeping the proportion (same amount of 1s and Os in the resampled sample) of my two variables (I and O) constant.
This is my data:

```
dat[,c(2,4,7)]
   I O SIDI.F
1  0 0     50
2  1 0     13
3  1 0     13
4  0 1     12
5  0 0     13
6  0 0     15
7  0 1     23
8  0 1     34
```

Since I could not find a way, I tried to make it easier and split the data set trying to at least keep the proportions constant for O or I:

```
> dat3
> O SIDI.F
> 1  0     50
> 2  0     13
> 3  0     13
> 4  1     12
> 5  0     13
```

```
> dat2
> I SIDI.F
> 1  0     50
> 2  1     13
> 3  1     13
> 4  0     12
> 5  0     13
```

```
datBoot2 <- dat2[sample(1:nrow(dat2), 8, replace=TRUE), ]
datBoot3 <- dat3[sample(1:nrow(dat2), 8, replace=TRUE), ]
```

However, still I can't find a way to keep the proportions (same number of 1s and 0s in the resampled dataset). Please, can anyone help?

Comment: You want to keep the proportions of 0's and 1' s constant? Then the only thing you can do is to randomly permute the vectors, but that is sampling **without replacement**!

Answer (score 1):

sampling (should?) require a kind of randomness... I believe the `rbinom()` function can be used here. The probablility of succes (x == 1) is calculated for the `prob`-argument, based on the original input.

```
mysample <- function(x) rbinom(length(x), 1, sum(x == 1)/length(x))
mysample(dat$O)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers! I seem to have found a solution. I found a code on a different post on stackoverflow and changes it for sampling with replacement. Although I do not understand the full code, it seems to work:

```
sampFreq<-function(cdf,col,ns) { 
  x<-as.factor(cdf[,col])  
  freq_x<-table(x)         
  prob_x<-freq_x/sum(freq_x)  
  df_prob = prob_x[as.factor(cdf[,col])]  
  nr=nrow(cdf) 
  sLevels = levels(as.factor(cdf[,col])) 
  nLevels = length(sLevels) 
  rat = ns/nr
  rdata = NULL
  for (is in seq(1,nLevels)) {
    ldata <- cdf[cdf[,col]==sLevels[is],]
    ndata <- nrow(ldata)
    nsdata = max(ndata*rat,1)
    srows <- sample(seq(1,ndata),nsdata,replace=TRUE)
    sdata <- ldata[srows,]
    rdata <- rbind(rdata,sdata)
  }
  return(rdata)
}

datSample <- sampFreq(dat,"I",19)
```

Checking the proportion of the new sample via the following code seems to  indicate the correct proportion.

```
freq_x<-table(datSample$I)
freq_x/sum(freq_x)
```